# Remove objects from list which have their related-related model the same

Tags: python, django

I believe it's pretty hard to understand the problem from the question, so I'll provide an answer.

I have the following relations between my models: `Answer` BelongsTo `Question` BelongsTo `Page`. I have a list of answers: `[<Answer: 1>, <Answer: 2>, ...]`.

Now I would like to remove *all* answers that belong to different questions that belong to the *same* page.

If, for example, my answer list contains the following (details added for clarity): `[<Answer: Q1P1>, <Answer: Q1P1>, <Answer: Q1P2>, <Answer: Q2P2>]` then only the last **two** answers should be removed from the list, because they both belong to different questions that belong to the same page. The first two answers remain there because although their question belongs to the same page, the question **is not different**.

My models roughly look like this:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    pass

class Question(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you post your models?

Comment: So, if i get you correctly, given a page, get all the unique answers associated with it ? Or do you want a queryset which has unique page-answer relationship ?

Comment: What is your _REAL_ use case ? Where does this list comes from (and is it really a list ? Or is it a Queryset ?) What do you need it for ?

If it's really a list then you can filter it out with a for loop or a list comprehesion or using the builtin `filter` function, but it's not really efficient.

Comment: In which group should the solution categorise an answer which is the only one to any question on a page?

Comment: @karthikr, I am given a bunch of answers, not a page. I need to group these answers by question (to eliminate multiple answers that a question can have), and delete each group of answers which belongs to different questions belonging to the same page.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, You are right, it is a Queryset, but I don't know how much difference this can make. The use case is quite complex. The given queryset of answers results from some algorithm of answer suggestion that will improve a test's overall result (a test is comprised of several `Page`s). And this suggestion is valid only if the above conditions I described are true.

Comment: @GarryCairns, I don't understand exactly what you have meant, but any answer whose question belongs to the same page (the question being different -- this is to avoid questions that have multiple answers from being treated as belonging to the same page) must be removed from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:

Let's say that we have an `answers` list.

```
# 1. Let's find out the pages:
pages = set([])
for a in answers:
 pages.add(a.question.page)
pages = list(pages)

# 2. Now for each page, 
for p in pages:
  # 2.a. find out the answers that belong to this page
  same_page_answers = [a for a in answers if a.question.page = p]
  # 2.b. find out the questions of these answers
  same_page_questions = set([])
  for a in same_page_answers:
    same_page_questions.add(a.question)
  same_page_questions = list(same_page_questions) 

  # 3. now we will check to see if each question appears at least twice
  for q in same_page_questions:
    same_page_question_answers = [a for a in same_page_answers if a.question=q]
    if len(same_page_question_answer) < 2:
      # Ok so the same_page_question_answers need to be removed from our initial answers
      answers = [a for a in answers if a not in same_page_question_answer]
      # actually if we are here same_page_question_answer will be an array with 1 element but in any case
```

Using your example

```
answers = [A1: Q1P1, A2: Q1P1, A3: Q1P2, A4: Q2P2]

pages = [P1, P2]

inside for loop for P1:
 same_page_answers = [A1, A2]
 same_page_questions = [Q1, Q1]
 inside for loop for Q1:
  len == 2 - we won't remove anything


inside for loop for P2:
 same_page_answers = [A3, A4]
 same_page_questions = [Q1, Q2]
 inside for loop for Q1:
  same_page_question_answers = [A3]
  len = 1 - we will remove [A3] from answers
 inside for loop for Q2:
  same_page_question_answers = [A4]
  len = 1 - we will remove [A4] from answers

answers = [A1,A2]
```

Hope it's working now :)

Comment: the OP wants to remove answers that belongs to "a different question from the same page"

Comment: I have no current page, I am provided only with a list (queryset) of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought it would be something easier, some Django specific stuff that will leverage this heavy process. But I'll go the "hard" way. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to do this using the django orm due to the complexity of the requirement :( Maybe it could be done using SQL but I believe its more clear with pure python...